# Register EntityManager from other project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I've created a maven utility project with jar packaging where I implemented EntityManager interface to manage database connection and stuff. But when i want to use it (from another maven project) with @Inject it does not work.

Is there a way to specify which EntityManager implementation I wan to to use?

Important: If I include this EntityManager in the main project, it works. But I'm trying to avoid this because in the future I'll have other projects using the same database.

Here is the exception I have.

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.gtwpedidos.test.CanalSurDao.em]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the right way to do this is to:

- 1st: make your utility project be an `EJB` and inside this `EJB` inject your `EntityManager`  with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation. This way the EntityManager will be handled by the EJB, i.e. the EntityManager is created when ,for example the `@Stateless` bean is created and destroyed when the `@Stateless` bean is destroyed.
- 2nd: Inject your `utility EJB` in the EJB of your main project by using the `@EJB` annotation

Rough example:

**UTILITY EJB**

```
@Stateless(name="UtilityEJB", mappedName="UtilityEJBGlobal")
public class UtilityEJB 
{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PRIMARY_PERSISTENCE_UNIT")
    public EntityManager em;

    //other stuff   ......
}
```

**MAIN PROJECT**

```
@Stateless
public class Main
{

    @EJB(mappedName="UtilityEJBGlobal")
    private UtilityEJB utilityEJB ;

    //other stuff   ......

}
```

In my case I had to use the mapped namings in order for my main project to find the already deployed `EJB` and inject it in the main one.

Hope it helps